# GCM with reversed poly

Tags: finite-field, gcm, aes-gcm

[These slides](https://crypto.stanford.edu/RealWorldCrypto/slides/gueron.pdf#page=16) talk about how GCM can be sped up if one uses $x^{128}+x^{127}+x^{126}+x^{121}+1$ as the reduction polynomial instead of $x^{128}+x^7+x^2+x^1+1$.

When one is doing that one needs to multiply the polynomial you're attempting to reduce by $x^{-127}$, "better written as" $x \cdot x^{-128}$. I have three questions about this...

- Does this need to be done in addition to and prior to the method described on [page 20 of those slides](https://crypto.stanford.edu/RealWorldCrypto/slides/gueron.pdf#page=20)? Like do I need to explicitly multiply every polynomial I'm trying to reduce (let's call this polynomial $y$) by $x^{-1}$ and add $y \ll 1$ and $y \ll 128$? My assumption is that it does but idk
- When page 20 of those slides say $x_0 \cdot C200000000000000_{16}$ does it mean to do integer multiplication or polynomial multiplication? Like with integer multiplication $5\cdot5=25 = 19_{16}$ whereas with polynomial multiplication over a binary finite field $5 \cdot 5$ could be interpreted as $(x^2 + 1)(x^2 + 1) = x^4+ x^2 + x^2 + 1 = x^4 + 1 = 11_{16}$. I'm assuming you're supposed to do integer multiplication but idk
- Is $C200000000000000_{16}$ supposed to be in big endian format or little endian format? I'm guessing little endian since that's what GCM uses? In that scenario then $C200000000000000_{16}$ could be rewritten more simply as $C2_{16}$ just as $0099$ can be rewritten as $99$.

Comment: Hint: $x^{-1}$ is the number that multiplied by $x$, modulo the reduction polynomial, makes $1$. You can find it and then compute its powers to obtain $x^{-2},...,x^{-127}$. However I believe that in this specific case the trick is to understand [Montgomery reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_modular_multiplication) and that $R=x^{128}$

Comment: I can't help linking this fantastic blog post dissecting Gueron's trick: https://blog.quarkslab.com/reversing-a-finite-field-multiplication-optimization.html